# Compute total marks and rank using dictionary in python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I've the following code for computing total marks and rank in python dictionary. Let me know is there any simple code available for this concept.

***Conditions are:***

- Add new key for storing total marks.
- Add new key for rank.
- Compute both marks and rank.

  `for key,value in student.items():
      smark = sum(student[key]["mark"])
      student[key].update({"total_marks":smark})
  s=sorted(student, key = lambda x:student[x]["total_marks"], reverse=True)
  rank = 1
  for key in s:
      student[key].update({"rank":rank})
      rank += 1`

**MY OUTPUT**

```
('a', {'rollno': 2001, 'age': 18, 'mark': [85, 65, 65], 'total_marks': 215, 'rank': 2})
('b', {'rollno': 2002, 'age': 18, 'mark': [85, 55, 65], 'total_marks': 205, 'rank': 3})
('c', {'rollno': 2003, 'age': 18, 'mark': [85, 95, 65], 'total_marks': 245, 'rank': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
student = {}
student["a"] = {"rollno":2001, "age":18, "mark":[85,65,65]}
student["b"] = {"rollno":2002, "age":18, "mark":[85,55,65]}
student["c"] = {"rollno":2003, "age":18, "mark":[85,95,65]}
rank = {}
for key,value in student.items():
    smark = sum(student[key]["mark"])
    student[key].update({"total_marks":smark})
s=sorted(student, key = lambda x:student[x]["total_marks"], reverse=True)
rank = 1
for key in s:
    student[key].update({"rank":rank})
    rank += 1
print("*** Rank of each student based on total marks *** \n")
for i in student.items():
    print(i)
```